# uncertain behaviour when combining selenium test cases into JUnit test suite

Tags: selenium, webdriver, junit4, test-suite

I have a scenario where I have 29 test cases. All the test cases pop-up new firefox windows and run to completion when run independently. However when I combine the test cases(all 29) into a test suite, I get random errors of "unable to locate element". If I run the test suite multiple times, I can see different test cases fail at different places, randomly. Note- I am waiting for every elements visibility for around 100 seconds, before clicking on them. Code looks like-

```
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 100))
    .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
    @Override
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(element);
    }
```

Could someone advice? Are smaller test suites recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not so far come across with a similar problem type.
IMHO try to use a lil bit more robust wait mechanism `fluentWait`:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
            Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);
            WebElement foo = wait.until(
                    new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                            return driver.findElement(locator);
                        }
                    }
            );
            return  foo;              }     ;
```

here is [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) on fluent wait

usage be like :

```
String cssSelectorElement ="blablablab";
String xPathElement = "balblabla";

fluentWait(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorElement)).click()
//fluentWait(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorElement)).getText();

fluentWait(By.xpath(xPathElement)).click()
//fluentWait(By.xpath(xPathElement)).getText();
```

Don't forget about step by step debug in IDE(IDEA, Eclipse,NetBeans) you work.

Comment: I had driver.quit commented out as I was debugging. Closing the firefox after every test did help the purpose. Will also take your advice on waiting robustly. Thank you.